# Make Jquery get element by Id and click it

Tags: jquery

I have two Ajax-methods in my code and I would like one of them to fire the other. It could be demonstrated like this:

```
 $(function() {
      //Code that "clicks #target" and triggers the mthod below.
    });

$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "The above method clicked #target" );
});
```

Been looking around a bit but im probably using the wrong searchterms.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just do:

```
$("#target").click();
```

This will invoke the defined click function for `#target`

Comment: That was fast! Thanks, i´ll mark as answer asap!

Comment: jQuery('#target').trigger('click'); does the same, using this you can trigger any event that is available for your element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
 $( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "The above method clicked #target" );
 });
});
```

`$(function(){});` is an alias for `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Your click handler is correct, too.